# Period-doubling bifurcation theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-points, bifurcation

I have the following definition of period-doubling bifurcation for a one-parameter family of functions $\left\{{ 
 F_{\lambda}  }\right\}$ :

**Definition.** A family of functions $\left\{{ 
  F_{\lambda}  }\right\}$  undergoes a period-doubling bifurcation at the parameter value $\lambda=\lambda_{0}$ if there exist an open interval $I$ and an $\epsilon >0$ such that:

1. For each $\lambda \in [\lambda_{0}-\epsilon,\lambda_{0}+\epsilon]$, there exist a unique fixed point $p_{\lambda}$ for $F_{\lambda}$ in $I$.
2. For $\lambda \in (\lambda_{0}-\epsilon, \lambda_{0})$ , $F_{\lambda}$ has not cycles of period $2$ in $I$ and $p_{\lambda}$ is attracting(resp. repelling).
3. For $\lambda \in (\lambda_{0},\lambda_{0}+\epsilon)$, there exist a unique 2-cycle  $q_{\lambda}^1,q_{\lambda}^2$ in $I$ with $F_{\lambda}(q_{\lambda}^1)=q_{\lambda}^2$. This 2-cycle is attracting (resp., repelling). Meanwhile, the fixed point $p_{\lambda}$ is repelling(resp., attracting).
4. As $\lambda \rightarrow{} \lambda_{0}$, $q_{\lambda}^i \rightarrow p_{\lambda_{0}}$.

Here, we use the notation $f^2=f \circ f$, and if the above conditions are valid with the order of the intervals $(\lambda_{0}-\epsilon, \lambda_{0})$, $(\lambda_{0},\lambda_{0}+\epsilon)$ switched , we also say that the family have a period-doubling bifurcation.

Once said that, I have found the following theorem which apparently implies the existence of a period-doubling bifurcation:

**Theorem.**  Suppose that:

1. $f_{\lambda}(x_{0})=x_{0}$ for all $\lambda$ in an interval about $\lambda_{0}$.
2. $f'_{\lambda_{0}}(x_{0})=-1$.
3. $   \displaystyle \frac{\partial (f^2_{\lambda})'}{\partial \lambda}  \Big |_{\lambda=\lambda_{0}}^{}(x_{0}) \neq 0 $.

Then there is an interval $I$ about $x_{0}$ and a function $p:I \rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ such that

$$
f_{p(x)}(x) \neq x
$$

But,

$$
f^{2}_{p(x)}=x
$$

My question is: Why this theorem implies the existence of such a bifurcation? I don't see it.

I understand that the condition $f'_{\lambda_{0}}(x_{0})=-1$ implies the first condition of the definition , to prove that we can apply the implicit function theorem.

I also see that the the existence of such a function $p$ implies the existence of a $2-$cycle, however, I can´t understand why this implies the other conditions of the definition.

Can anyone explain me please?

In advance, thank you.

Comment: This is just my guess. You can rewrite $F_{\lambda}(x)$ as $$F(x, \lambda) = x_0 + a_1 (\lambda) (x-x_0) + a_2(\lambda) \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} + o((x-x_0)^2), $$ it is a consequence of condition 1. If you fiddle with formula for $F(x, \lambda)$ and $F(F(x, \lambda), \lambda)$, you will see that conditions 2 and 3 provide that $a_1(\lambda_0) = -1$ and $a'_1(\lambda_0) \neq 0$ — it means that stability of $x_0$ changes when passing through $\lambda_0$. The same conditions 2 and 3 probably allow to use IFT and prove that there is a unique pair of 2-periodic points — but that is just my guess.

Comment: @Evgeny thanks for the idea, let me move the pencil and see if it works :) , if it does I'll write the answer.